# multiple forms to be sent to different PHP pages using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

Hi the website i have built has multiple forms that i want to handle using AJAX, each request goes to a separate PHP page and returns a string.

HTML

```
<form name="addUserModule" id="addUserModule" action=""  method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="moduleToADD[]" value="1">
<input type="submit" value="Save" id="addUserModuleSubmit">

<form action="" method ="post" id="addNewModule" name="addNewModule">
<input type="text" name="newModule"> 
<input type="submit" value="Add Module" id="addNewModuleSubmit">
```

Jquery

```
$('#addUserModule').submit(function(e){
 e.preventDefault(); //Prevent the normal submission action
 var form = this;
  $.ajax({
url:'addUserModules.php',
data:$(form).serialize(),
type:'POST',
success: function(msg) {
        displayNotification(msg);
    }
});   
});

$('#addNewModule').submit(function(e){
 e.preventDefault(); //Prevent the normal submission action
 var form = this;
  $.ajax({
url:'addNewModule.php',
data:$(form).serialize(),
type:'POST',
success: function(msg) {
        displayNotification(msg);
    }
});   
});
```

The first form works fine, but the second form runs the same function that i made for the first form. Im using the HTML id's to determine the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your html code you havent closed your `form` and hence it is behaving like that.

```
<form name="addUserModule" id="addUserModule" action=""  method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="moduleToADD[]" value="1">
<input type="submit" value="Save" id="addUserModuleSubmit">
</form>
<form action="" method ="post" id="addNewModule" name="addNewModule">
<input type="text" name="newModule"> 
<input type="submit" value="Add Module" id="addNewModuleSubmit">
</form>
```

Now it will work fine.

Check this fiddle [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/madhust/Vvrd6/)

Comment: Good catch ... you have a keen eye :)

Comment: darn, thanks so much..any tips for keeping an eye out for things like that in the future ecspeciallay when doing it in PHP?